# Force dataTips to Display on Flex Grap Permanently

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I assume I need to override the mouse over and mouse off event so that they don't do anything and then trigger the mouse over event for each column on the graph.

Anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use data labels:

> By default, BarSeries, ColumnSeries, and PieSeries objects do not
>   display data labels.
>
> To enable data labels on **BarSeries and
>   ColumnSeries** objects, set the value of the **labelPosition property
>   to inside or outside**.
>
> To enabled data labels on **PieSeries**, set the value of the
>   **labelPosition property to inside, outside, callout, or
>   insideWithCallout**.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the property showAllDataTips for the chart to true.
This will force all the available dataTips on the chart to become visible.

I guess this should do what you are trying to get done.

The mouseover event for the graph seems a long shot but its still feasible incase you want to show data tips on some kind of interaction.

But I would suggest on mouse rollover , change showAddDataTips= true and on rollOut showAllDataTips=false .

That should do the trick.